# Displaying map on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I want to display maps in my application in Kindle Fire Device. Google map is one of the best option to display the map in Android devices, but kindle fire does not support google API.
While searching for the alternate API. I have found several API's like **"Mapquest"** and **"Open Street Map"** as the options. I have tried to develop sample application using Mapquest and Open Street Map but still I am not able to display the map on Kindle because all those API's having functionality which is using device's GPS and *Kindle does not support GPS*.
I think one of the option is to alter the jar.
Can anyone suggest API's to display the map in Kindle Fire or 
any other better options to do the same?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Kindle Fire have sdk for debugging app in emulator

Answer (score 1):

There is no "official" map API on the kindle fire. For my app, we load a webpage with Google Maps javascript into a webview and interact with that webpage using javascript. You might consider the following:

1. Using data from the network location provider on the device and building a javascript based html page that can be loaded into the webview. Then, injecting the current device location into the page using either `webvie.loadurl(javascript:...` or [adding a javascript interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and accessing that from inside the javascript.
2. Removing the map functionality from your kindle fire app. The device really isn't targeted at maps like uses like a cell phone so maybe your app doesn't need a map in the kindle fire version. Obviously, this depends on what type of app you are making.

Comment: I am able to display the Map in Kindle fire using **Mapquest** you can download the SDK, here is the link: [link](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Now Amazon offers a full featured Maps API that is said to [have interface parity](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/maps/faq.html) with the Google API so that it might be easy to integrate. More details here https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/maps.html
Here are the directions to migrate an app using Google Maps to Amazon Maps https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/maps/migrating.html

Answer (score 0):

i would recomend using OpenStreetMaps, i have my self got rid of google maps and got OSM and you can then use Bing Renderrer, works much better

this way you can target all tablets including Kindle and mobile which dont have GAPI following link may help

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

for Bing Renderrer look @
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-third-party/src/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/bing/BingMapTileSource.java?r=967

- pre req you need BING api key in manifest easy to get
  BingMapTileSource.retrieveBingKey(getApplicationContext());
  bingMapTileSource = new BingMapTileSource();
  mMapView.setTileSource(bingMapTileSource);

This has a working example too you can play around to see